# Do not retrieve if all or one of the supplied category is existing

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below database and my problem is that I want to query all `list_id` in `my_list` table where its corresponding `list_risk_code` is `'600'` and its `info_risk_code` are all `'400'`

```
table: my_info_list
info_id        list_id
1              1
2              1
3              1
4              2
5              2
6              3
7              3

table: my_info 
info_id        info_risk_code
1              '400'
2              '600'
3              '400'
4              '600'
5              '600'
6              '400'
7              '400'


table: my_list
list_id        list_risk_code
1              '600'
2              '600'
3              '600'
```

My desired output below, because, `list_id` 1 has 3 `info_risk_code`(400,600 and 400) but one of them is 600 so it wont be included. the `list_id` 2 has 2 `info_risk_code`(600,600) but both of them are 600 so it is disregarded also. only `list_id` 3 is retrieve because it has 2 `info_risk_code` which are both 400:

```
my_list.list_id        info_risk_code     list_risk_code
3                      '600'              '400'
```

right now my code is below which gets 1 and 3 for they both contain non-600 info_risk_code. which is incorrect :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ml.list_id
   ,info_risk_code as c_rr
   ,list_risk_code as a_rr
FROM 
    my_list AS ml
    INNER JOIN my_info_list AS mil ON mil.list_id = ml.list_id
    INNER JOIN my_info AS mi ON mil.info_id = mi.info_id
WHERE 
    (
            (info_risk_code = '600' OR info_risk_code = '360') 
        AND (NOT list_risk_code = '600' AND NOT list_risk_code = '360')
    )
    OR 
    (
            (NOT info_risk_code = '600' AND NOT info_risk_code = '360') 
        AND (list_risk_code = '600' OR list_risk_code = '360')
    )
```

for your trial/reference you can use this:

```
CREATE TABLE my_info_list(
    info_id INT,
    list_id INT
);

CREATE TABLE my_info(
    info_id INT,
    info_risk_code varchar(5)
);

CREATE TABLE my_list(
    list_id INT,
    list_risk_code varchar(5)
);


INSERT INTO my_info_list VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO my_info_list VALUES (2,1);
INSERT INTO my_info_list VALUES (3,1);
INSERT INTO my_info_list VALUES (4,2);
INSERT INTO my_info_list VALUES (5,2);
INSERT INTO my_info_list VALUES (6,3);
INSERT INTO my_info_list VALUES (7,3);

INSERT INTO my_info VALUES (1,'400');
INSERT INTO my_info VALUES (2,'600');
INSERT INTO my_info VALUES (3,'400');
INSERT INTO my_info VALUES (4,'600');
INSERT INTO my_info VALUES (5,'600');
INSERT INTO my_info VALUES (6,'400');
INSERT INTO my_info VALUES (7,'400');

INSERT INTO my_list VALUES (1,'600');
INSERT INTO my_list VALUES (2,'600');
INSERT INTO my_list VALUES (3,'600');
```

Coding for almost an hour now with this query, need some idea. Thank you

Comment: I think there is an error in the sample data provided in the first table: fields `list_id` and `info_id` should be switched.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos yes sorry :) you have good eye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ml.list_id, info_risk_code as c_rr, list_risk_code as a_rr
FROM my_list AS ml
INNER JOIN my_info_list AS mil
  ON mil.list_id = ml.list_id
INNER JOIN my_info AS mi
  ON mil.info_id = mi.info_id
WHERE mi.info_risk_code = '400' AND 
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM my_info_list AS mil2
                  INNER JOIN my_info AS mi2 ON mil2.info_id = mi2.info_id
                  WHERE mil2.list_id = ml.list_id AND mi2.info_risk_code <> '400')
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5fd64/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `group by` query to only select `list_id` values where all `info_risk_codes` are 400 and the associated `list_risk_code` is 600

```
select ml.list_id 
from my_list ml 
join my_info_list mil on ml.list_id = mil.list_id
join my_info mi on mil.info_id = mi.info_id
where ml.list_risk_code = '600'
group by ml.list_id
having sum(info_risk_code <> '400') = 0
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b9e9/1